# Super User em português

Tags: debate, superuser, area51

O que vocês acham de propormos a criação do Super User em português no [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/)?

Por que especificamente o [Super User](https://superuser.com/)? A verdade é que alguns sites da rede como o [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) e o [Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) se incluem dentro do escopo da programação e portanto suas criações não fazem sentido visto que a quantidade de acesso do SO-pt é relativamente baixa e ele pode perfeitamente absorver essas perguntas.

Porém o Super User tem a proposta de atender perguntas que fogem do escopo da programação. E muitas vezes nós (programadores) também sentimos a necessidade de um espaço para perguntas desse tipo (um exemplo: configuração de servidores Linux). É claro que ele também atenderia pessoas que trabalham com suporte e mesmo usuários comuns em geral.

Como sou relativamente novo nos sites [Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com/), não sei os detalhes da criação de um novo site (se é fácil ou difícil, quanto apoio precisa ter, etc.). É também pra discutir isso que criei esta pergunta.

Comment: Dados totalmente não-cientificos que podia ser legal saber:  quantos dos que [fizeram *commitment*](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/23539?phase=commitment) participam atualmente aqui. . . . Só vi uma proposta de SU em Español, com 2, dois, seguidores...

Comment: Eu criei uma proposta de SU e não foi pra frente. De qualquer foerma não vai acontecer outro site em português tão cedo. Na verdade depois que o nosso site se firmar de vez, a prioridade será lançar o SO em outras línguas, conforme fila do Area 51. Antes de graduarmos não é uma boa ideia tentar nada.

Comment: @brasofilo De fato entre os primeiros da lista poucos eu vi por aqui.

Comment: Estava agora mesmo olhando o A51. Tem uns percentuais à esse respeito na [barra lateral](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/23539?phase=beta). Anyway, concordo com @bigown, acredito que a chance pra um SUPT só deve acontecer lá pra frente (chutando, talvez depois de 2017/2018)

Comment: Existe uma proposta de um site sobre café. É o quarto da lista "hot", pelo tipo vai sair. =) http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/61013/coffee

Comment: @Andrey Não entendi. A única proposta que deve permitir português e que pode sair logo é http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/64172/portuguese-language. Mas oficialmente este é um site em inglês. O português poderá ser usado, mas opcionalmente. Além disso a interface será em inglês. Pelo menos esta é a ideia desses sites de línguas até agora.

Comment: @bigown Já vi antes este sobre português e já cliquei em *Follow* também. Sobre o site sobre café: não tem nada a ver com esta pergunta mesmo, só citei porque achei interessante/diferente, tem 115 *follows* atualmente.

Comment: Seria bem interessante. Tô cansado de fazer backup dos meus jogos na unha toda vez que preciso formatar o PC porque o Windows inventou mais um problema cabeludo que ninguém sabe resolver e eu sou obrigado a formatar.

Comment: Eu diria que seria interessante ter todos os sites em todas as línguas, ou melhor, todos os sites voltados para todas as línguas; por exemplo: Super User para pessoas que falam português. Inicialmente não precisa ser em português, com o tempo a comunidade poderia ir traduzindo tudo. Penso que a única implicação seria o número de sites gerados, daria, realmente, muito trabalho para administrar tudo de forma eficiente.

Comment: @brasofilo Vejo que você não frequenta o site há um bom tempo. Pois bem, a proposta na Area 51 está de pé e evoluindo rápido, talvez você queira se juntar a nós.

Answer (score 8):

Acho que chegou a hora da criação. Veja:

## [Super User em Português](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/84282/super-user-em-portugues).